# Python modules for GIS visualization tool

Tags: python, gis

First of all, sorry for my English, since is not my mother tongue.

I decided to develop an interactive GIS visualization tool for my Bachelor's project.

I would like to code it in python, since it is my language-to-go for my projects in console. While my backend is already chosen, I'm kind of amused about the variety and interdependence of modules.

My idea is to develop a tool able to:
- Extracts slices from a database.(mongo)
- Performs filters in the dataset (pandas)
- Normalizes the geocoordinates (geopandas, numpy)
- Plots the data in an undefined form.
- All the previous features should be interfaced by a web frontend.

And here comes the point of my question. Apparently bokeh leads to panel, panel leads to jupyter, jupyter leads to bokeh... and so on.

There are so many exciting projects, but the market is too wide in options, and the deeper I research, the more layered appears to be the scene.

I just need to research in ONE particular direction. What would it be a closed (preferably short) list of modules to focus to accomplish my project?
Books for references would be appreciated.